# add/modify php n level associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

```
$arrResult=array(
0=>array('categoryid'=>112,'catname'=>'apperal','subcategory'=>array(
412=>array('categoryid'=>428,'catname'=>'rainwear','subcategory'=>array(
428=>array('categoryid'=>413,'catname'=>'summer','subcategory'=>array()))))));

print_r($arrResult);


$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($arrResult); 
iterator_apply($iterator, 'traverseStructure', array($iterator)); 

function traverseStructure($iterator) {
   $arrAddResult=array('categoryid'=>416,'catname'=>'winter','subcategory'=>array());

    while ( $iterator -> valid() ) {

        if ( $iterator -> hasChildren() ) {

            traverseStructure($iterator -> getChildren());

        }
        else {

            if($iterator -> current() == 413)
            {
                $arr=&$iterator;
                $a='arr';                           
                            ${$a}['subcategory']=$arrAddResult;
                break;
            }
        }
        $iterator -> next();
    }
}
```

the expected output is to append the 'arrAddResult' appenedn in  $arrResult. But with some reason the iterator get modify but it doesn't reflect the modification in arrResult array.

I tried passing the array by ref in function 'traverseStructure' but still struggling to get the correct output.

I am trying iterator first. I have to constructor a N-Level associative array as arrResult hence opt to use the iterator.

Comment: I don't think iterator is best used here if I understand the logic of that code. Is this the actual scenario you are using it in ?

Comment: Problem : I have to construct N- nested level of associative array. '$arrResult' array is associative array which is nested. I wanted to add $arrAddResult as part of $arrResult. the parent of $arrAddResult is the category id 413.

I thought Iterator will help me to walk array recursively and when I will find the matching key I will append the $arrAddResult to $arrResult.
If there are other way to perform this please share

Comment: If all your iterator does is find the ending array, wouldn't a function that find the last child be far more suited ? How do you plan on using it? I feel strongly about not using iterator in this scenario.

Comment: okie. Then what is the better solution to construct N-level associative array?

Comment: You still haven't shown you plan on using it. Do you always have array(one_index => array('cat','name','sub')) where 'sub' repeats this model ?

Comment: Yes. 'sub' will repeat the same .

Comment: I wihs I could share the print_r($arrResult) which can make more sense.

Comment: In this example you seem to have 2 children in child1. Is that the case? +1 for dragging this convo for 5 hours.

Comment: I think I have already defined $arrResult array likewise in the problem itself?.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 direct descendant in any array ?

Comment: It can be possible. It is something like you have a parent category Now, this can have 5 child then each child can have more subchild and each subchild can have more sub sub childs with in it .No limit defined for horizontal or vertical level for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example on a way of doing this with one array.

```
<?php
$arrResult=array(
    1=>array('categoryid'=>112,'catname'=>'apperal','subcategory'=>array()),
    0=>array('categoryid'=>112,'catname'=>'apperal','subcategory'=>array(
        1=>array('categoryid'=>112,'catname'=>'rainwear','subcategory'=>array(
            1=>array('categoryid'=>112,'catname'=>'apperal','subcategory'=>array()),
            428=>array('categoryid'=>413,'catname'=>'summer','subcategory'=>array()))
            ),
        412=>array('categoryid'=>428,'catname'=>'rainwear','subcategory'=>array(
            1=>array('categoryid'=>112,'catname'=>'apperal','subcategory'=>array()),
            428=>array('categoryid'=>413,'catname'=>'summer','subcategory'=>array()))
            )
        )
    )
);

function append(&$ar,$who,$what){
    // just a simple check, you can remove it
    if(!is_array($ar))return false;
    // loop through all keys
    foreach($ar as $k=>$v){
        // found node, i'm assuming you don't have the node multiple times
            // if you want this to go forever, remove the returns and the if on the add()
        if($v['categoryid']==$who){
            $ar[$k]['subcategory'][]=$what;
            return true;
        }
        // recursion !
        if(add($ar[$k]['subcategory'],$who,$what))return true;// if found stop
    }
    // key not found here in this node or subnodes
    return false;
}
append($arrResult,413,array('categoryid'=>416,'catname'=>'winter','subcategory'=>array()));
echo'<pre>';
var_dump($arrResult);
```

This might be inefficient on large arrays. I'd recommend making a class that caches the $who  and $what so it doesn't get copied to all the levels of the traversal. The rest should be identical.

Comment: Thanks It works. I will try to use the logic in my main program where I am already using recursion there but I was not able to correctly track the array key to append the array at correct index. This would help.

Comment: If you need any help, feel free to ask.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but where is the add() function defined?